# Testing DNS for samba to function properly - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, samba, dns, raspberrypi

I'm currently following a guide to set-up a Samba AD DC on Ubuntu 14.04 with a Raspberry Pi 2, here's the link: "https://jimshaver.net/2014/07/13/setting-up-an-active-directory-domain-controller-using-samba-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/"

Right now i'm trying to test out the DNS but whenever i type the command that the guide suggests i get a error message.
Here's the code:

```
$ host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.weemaniac.net
$ command not found
```

I also couldn't figure out some of the previous steps like editing the /etc/fstabs or /etc/hosts
I'm inexperienced with Ubuntu and pretty much all Linux distros in general but i'd really like to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't use the hosts command is because you are missing the dnsutils package which can be installed by typing the following command

```
Sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```

This package should have been installed when you copied and pasted the long `sudo apt-get install` at the start. So check your not missing other dependencies.

It should be very easy to edit your hosts file by typing the following:

```
Sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

To then save your changes press CTRL+o and then hit enter then CTRL+x to exit the text editor.

When following that particular guide editing the fstab is not a required step just if you want to enable  ACLs (access control lists) on that disk and by extension your domain shares.

I've found this to be the best and easiest tutorial to follow so stick with it and you will come out with a working DC at the end!

Comment: It says i already installed the dnsutils package, still not working though.

Comment: Have you checked that you installed all the other dependencies? Try running the Sudo apt-get install package list on the tutorial again and see if it wants to install more packages

Comment: I restarted the Raspberry Pi and the command is giving me a different error message now: "Host _ldap._tcp.weemaniac.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: Did you manage to update your hosts file ? Did you edit the /network/interfaces as demonstrated in the demo? Could you post the global section of your smb.conf ?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had not seen the one you are using, I built my AD-DC on 16.04LTS and used this guide.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2146198

The only problem I have had is in getting Samba to start on reboot, but this seems to be a 16.04 issue, this guide seems to work for older Ubuntu.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2132259

I have built and rebuilt this server on hardware, as well as virtual, and it has worked every time.  So my suggestion is, go step by step in the guide you have, and compare it to the one I am giving you, and see if there was a step missed.

Comment: BTW, my guide works best if during the server install you do not install anything else, the only thing I have installed with it has been SSH just so I could remote the terminal.